# What would be the pandas equivalent for the for-loop below?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function called unit_unify() that I want to apply to every column of the dataframe. I have been trying to devise the pandas equivalent using apply/apply map, but have not been successul.

Here is the for loop

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = unit_unify(df[i], unit_dict)
```

Here is the attempt at the pandas equivalent of the for loop

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: unit_unify(df[col], unit_dict))
```

Comment: [`df.apply(unit_unify, args=(unit_dict, ))`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: What exactly does your function do? There may be a more efficient way of implementing it~

Comment: @BeRT2me it takes in strings like "4 shots" and converts them into ounces using a unit conversion dictionary and another nested function that converts fractions into decimals.

Comment: So, the function is designed to be run on every single cell individually, the column/row that it's in doesn't matter, and the `unit_dict` is the same for every cell?

Answer (score 0):

You may check the performance for the for loop and `apply`:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/7964527)

```
[df[i] = unit_unify(df[i], unit_dict) for i in df.columns]
```